USB microphone isn't shown in alsamixer
How can I adjust the level of my USB microphone, because it isn't shown in alsamixer?

press F4 to select card

Thanks, I know you meant F6 I was surprised to see my usb microphone as a selectable sound card in the drop down list Even still it didn't help me raise the mic volume which only comes in at .1 decibel and if I clap my hands at the microphone it jumps up to .4
